# How to proceed training after stopping it and changing some parameters?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm training my model via model.fit() in Keras. I stopped the training, by interrupting it, or even because it is done, and then changed the batch_size and decided to go with more training. Here is what's happening:

The loss when the training was stopped/finished = 26

The loss when the training proceeded = 46

Meanining that I lost all the progress I made and it is as if I'ms starting over.
It does procceed from where it left only if I don't change anything. But if I changed the batch size, it is as if the optimizer re-initializes my weights and throw out my progress. How can I get a handle on what the optimizer is doing without my consent ?

Comment: How is loss calculated? Are you averaging loss over all examples in a minibatch or  adding them up? What is your batch size before and after? If you switched back to original batch size do you still see some number very different from 26?

Comment: Great question, the loss is mse, and I assume Keras give the average, right? So, it is a valid measure to compare two models without knowing what batch_size is. I just changed the it back in the third time, no change! Woah! what does that mean?

Comment: So what was the batch size before and after?

Comment: 64 first
changed it to 1000
changed it back to 64
In the second change, it seemed like I was proceeding, which make sense. But not in the first change when I spotted a change (increase) in loss.

Comment: You most likely have some examples that give you large loss values. MSE makes this worse. When batch size is larger then you are probably getting a lot of these outliers in your batch. You can look at the top loss contributing examples.

Comment: Ahh, got it! Many thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192537/discussion-between-dgumo-and-alex-deft).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely have some examples that give you large loss values. MSE makes this worse. When batch size is larger then you are probably getting a lot of these outliers in your batch. You can look at the top loss contributing examples.